# Recursively look up directories, (a little bit) slow

Tags: java, performance, file-system, file-structure, visitor-pattern

I wrote some Java code to look up all files in a chosen directory (like it's showing in the Windows Explorer), and to display the results, but it seems to be slow. Can you tell me, how to speed up it?

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    HashMap<Path, CarsAndSizes> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (!map.containsKey(dir)) {
            map.put(dir, new CarsAndSizes(dir, 0, 0));
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        Path p = file.getParent();
        long a = file.toFile().length();
        while (p != null && map.containsKey(p)) {
            map.get(p).incCar().addSize(a);
            p = p.getParent();
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    // If there is some error accessing
    // the file, let the user know.
    // If you don't override this method
    // and an error occurs, an IOException
    // is thrown.
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
        j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        j.showOpenDialog(null);
        Main m = new Main();
        Files.walkFileTree(j.getSelectedFile().toPath(), m);

        Object[][] oa = new Object[m.map.size()][3];
        int i = 0;
        for (Entry<Path, CarsAndSizes> e : m.map.entrySet()) {
            oa[i][0] = e.getKey().toString();
            oa[i][1] = e.getValue().car;
            oa[i][2] = e.getValue().size;
            i++;
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(oa, new String[] { "Path", "Cars", "Sizes" }) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 2:
                    return Long.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        for (int k = model.getRowCount() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if ((Integer) model.getValueAt(k, 1) == 0)
                model.removeRow(k);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CarsAndSizes implements Comparable<CarsAndSizes> {
    Path p;
    int car;
    long size;

    CarsAndSizes(Path p, int car, long size) {
        super();
        this.p = p;
        this.car = car;
        this.size = size;
    }

    CarsAndSizes incCar() {
        car++;
        return this;
    }

    CarsAndSizes addSize(long a) {
        size += a;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CarsAndSizes other = (CarsAndSizes) obj;
        return Objects.equals(p, other.p);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CarsAndSizes o) {
        if (car == o.car) {
            if (size == o.size)
                return p.compareTo(o.p);
            else
                return Long.compare(o.size, size);
        }
        return Integer.compare(o.car, car);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("CarsAndSizes [p=%s, car=%10s, size=%10s]", p, car, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: First step is to put in timers and start pin pointing what exactly is slow.